# Difference between two arrays containing numbers as string

Tags: php, arrays, string, difference

I´ve got a question about compairing two (text)arrays. I obtained two arrays from a loop containing numbers as shown below:

```
array(96) { [1]=> string(2) "20" [2]=> string(2) "18" [3]=> string(2)...
array(96) { [1]=> string(3) "135" [2]=> string(3) "103" [3]=> string(2) "88"
```

What I want is a new array which contains the difference of the values (1-2). This means that the 2 arrays above will results in the following new (text)array

```
array(96) { [1]=> string(3) "-115" [2]=> string(3) "-85" [3]=> string(2)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Try using `array_map`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with one `foreach`-loop. And then substract them from each other. You just need the same count of elements in `$array` and in `$array2`.

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $new[] = (string) ($val - $array2[$key]);
}
```

If it doesn't matter if the values are integers, you can remove the type casting `(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a function,

```
function foo($array1, $array2){
$resultArray = array();
for($i=0; i<count($array1); $i++){
$resultArray[] = (string)((int)$array1[$i] - (int)$array2[$i]);
}
return $resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help :)

```
<?php

    $a=array(20,18);
    $b=array(135,103);

    function fr($d,$d1){    
        global $c;
        $c[]=$d-$d1;
    }

    array_map('fr',$a,$b);

    var_dump($c);
```